# Maxima: integration of `charfun` containing array items

Tags: arrays, integration, maxima

If I run the following code

```
q: charfun(x>a);
assume(a<b);
integrate(q,x,a,b);
```

Maxima is able to compute the value of integral, which is `b-a`, but if I run the same calculation using items from an indexed array `x[i]` and `x[i+1]` in place of `a` and `b`, as below,

```
q: charfun(x>x[i]);
assume(x[i]<x[i+1]);
integrate(q,x,x[i],x[i+1]);
```

Maxima is not able to perform the symbolic computation and returns

[image]

instead of `x[i+1]-x[i]`. Is there a way to make Maxima calculate the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think Maxima is getting confused that the variable of integration `x` also appears in the limits of integration. If you change the variable of integration to be something else, you get the expected result, I think.

```
q: charfun(u>x[i]);
assume(x[i]<x[i+1]);
integrate(q,u,x[i],x[i+1]);
```

yields `x[i+1]-x[i]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not think about the most obvious explanation because for some reason I was convinced that `x` was completely indipendent of `x[ ]`, but evidently I was wrong.

Comment: @mmj By the way, for what overall purpose or goal are you computing integrals of charfuns? I have worked on related problems over the years.

Comment: I'm trying to explore the finite element theory (I'm a civil engineer) with Maxima, so I used `charfun` to define the base (piecewise) functions of solution and weighting function spaces, in order to make Maxima compute the (symbolic) integrals of the different resulting equations, and finally the stiffness and mass matrices.

Comment: Hmm, terrific, sounds interesting. Maxima doesn't have much built-in support for piecewise functions; there have been various attempts at add-on packages. I've been working on convolutions of piecewise functions in the last few days, maybe some of the code I have written would be useful to you. Let me know if you get stuck and I can try to help. By the way, probably the best forum for answering Maxima questions is the mailing list: maxima-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net

Comment: Thanks for your interest and appreciation, I will certainly look (again) for your help if I get stuck.